# Java- Square of Stars(Can't use right line breaks)

Tags: java, netbeans

Essentially the purpose of the program is to create a square of stars such as:

```
***
***
***
```

In order to do so I need to utilze a premade function such as

```
public static void printStars(int amount) {
    int counter = 0;
    while (counter < amount) {
        System.out.print("*");
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Right now the issue with my code is that I create

```
***

***

***
```

Or I create

```
*********

public static void printSquare(int sideSize) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < sideSize) {
        printStars(sideSize);
        i++;
    }
}
```

This one will produce the stars as one line. Apparently from the test it seems that I need to input a line break in the first function but when i do that it creates a much larger line break as I think the solution is

```
public static void printStars(int amount) {
    int counter = 0;
    while (counter < amount) {
        System.out.print("*");
        counter++;
    }
system.out.print("\n");
}
```

Due to that the Line break used is much larger.

So my question is: How do I make the correct line break?

Thank you in advance and sorry for such a similar question.

TLDR:
Keep making

```
***

***

***
```

instead of

```
***
***
***
```

Comment: Have you tried nesting two loops? (one loop inside another) Also, a for-loop might be better suited for doing this

Comment: Right now the course i am trying to do has not introduced for-loop so i am not sure if I should learn to do it yet for if it will be introduced later.

Comment: You'll have to make a decision. Either have the line break in `printStars`, or in the loop in `printSquare`. It may help to step through your program with a debugger.

Comment: Another thing you could do is check if your counter is divisible by 3 (`if (counter % 3 == 0)`) and only print a newline in that case

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke If I understand it right, the OP is very new to Java. I think it's better not to overwhelm them with the many different ways in which this can be done. (That said, _after_ they get the assignment done, it'll be fine for them to experiment with these alternatives! Experimentation is a great way to learn programming.)

Comment: I just realized my problem. I have been using System.out.println("\n") instead of system.out.print("\n"). Sorry for not realizing my mistake

Comment: @S.L.Barth it was not my intention to overwhelm the OP. If-statements and operators are generally taught early on though, so it seemed safe to mention as an option. And having known about a modulo operator would have saved me a lot of time in my early programming days, so it seemed right to at least mention it

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in the coding where instead of using

```
System.out.print("/n")
```

I used

```
System.out.println("/n")
```

meaning that two line breaks are printed instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `StringBuilder` to more easily control what to print (and finally just print it in one line with `System.out.println()`:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        printSquare(3);
    }

    public static void printStars(int amount) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
            builder.append("*");
        }
        System.out.println(builder.toString());
    }

    public static void printSquare(int amount) {
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
            printStars(amount);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code help you printing the desired output i.e.

```
***
***
***

public class PrintPattern {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            printStars(5);
        }
    }

    public static void printStars(int amount) {
        int counter = 0;
        while (counter < amount) {
            System.out.print("*");
            counter++;
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }

}
```